What differs std::to_string() from static_cast<std::string>()?
While on LearnCpp.com, I stumbled across a function called std::to_string(), but the tutorial didn't really elaborate on what it exactly did different than static_cast<std::string>(), so now I'm confused.
Also, std::string is a type, right?
I attempted to use them and got a compiler error, so I want to know in which scenario should I use std::to_string() or static_cast<std::string>().
'static_cast': cannot convert from 'char' to 'std::string'

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char x{ 'a' };

    std::cout << std::to_string(x) << "\n";
    std::cout << static_cast<std::string>(x) << "\n";
    return 0;
}


from where did you get the idea that the two should be the same? You already know they are not, but still ask for the difference.

std::to_string is very differet than a cast. Unlike a cast which marely changes the interpretation of the object (and naturally has certain limitations), std::to_string actually creates a new object (std::string) which is the textual representation of the original object.

You might read the doc std::to_string for more information.

The URL of the page on LearnCpp.com you're referring to might be helpful. Please [edit].

@wohlstad. Technically, static_cast can convert from one class to another if there is a conversion operator. But in this case, there is no (user-defined) conversion operator from char to std::string.

@André you are right, my comment is not 100% accurate. But I tried to give the gist of the fact that a cast and using std::string is very different.

@wohlstad "unlike a cast which marely changes the interpretation of the object" is generally not correct. even for a simple case of casting double to an int, is not merely a reinterpretation of the same object, but results in an int object. Your distinction isnt sound

@463035818_is_not_an_ai fair enough. I tried to simplify the issue but aparently failed ...

Another way to go from your x variable to a string is: std::cout << std::string(1, x) << "\n";

std::to_string is a function from the standard library. It has many overloads for different argument types that all return a std::string. I recommend to be careful with using it with a char. It might not do what you expect.
static_cast on the other hand is not a function, it's a language feature. It attempts a static cast conversion. There is no conversion from char to std::string, hence static_cast<std::string>(x) is an error.
There is no reason to expect the two to do the same thing.
